# Python dataframe new column with value based on value in other row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have another simple question as a follow up from here.
[Python pandas dataframe sum numbers until they change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763203/python-pandas-dataframe-sum-numbers-until-they-change)

I want to analyze a serie of numbers which go up and down. So far I have this code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2], columns=['A'])
df['UD'] = np.where(df['A'].pct_change().gt(0), 1, np.where(df['A'].pct_change().lt(0), -1, 0))
df['ST'] = df['UD'].groupby((df['UD'].ne(df['UD'].shift(1))).cumsum()).cumsum()
df['TB'] = np.where(df['A'].pct_change().ge(0) & df['A'].pct_change().shift(-1).le(0), 'T', np.where(df['A'].pct_change().le(0) & df['A'].pct_change().shift(-1).ge(0), 'B', ''))
print(df)
```

- Column UD has a 1 when the number goes up, a -1 when the number goes down and a 0 when the number doesn't change.
- Column ST is how often the number went up or down (from the answer in my previous question).
- Column TB has a T when the number is at the top and a B when the number is at the bottom.

Now I want a new column with how much the number changed since the last Top or Bottom. So the output will look like this.

```
    A  UD  ST TB     C
0   8   0   0     
1   2  -1  -1  B  
2   4   1   1     2.00
3   5   1   2     2.50
4   6   1   3  T  3.00
5   4  -1  -1     0.67
6   3  -1  -2  B  0.50
7   5   1   1  T  1.67
8   5   0   0  T  1.00
9   3  -1  -1     0.60
10  2  -1  -2     0.40
```

My first thought was to use shift() with the value of column ST.

```
df['CS'] = df['A'] / df['A'].shift(df['ST'].abs())
```

This throws an error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My second thought was to use iloc with the value of column ST.

```
df['CS'] = df['A'] / df['A'].iloc[df.index - df['ST'].abs()]
```

But that throws another error.

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: why does the C column contain floating point values? Why is the change from 2 to 5 (row 4) equal to 2.5 and not to 3?

Comment: Are your values for `C` correct or just guesses? They do not seem to match your definition “how much the number has changed since the last Top or Bottom”

Comment: flyinthelotion and cimbali, based on calculations he provides, "changes" means "percentage of changes".

Comment: Jane Doe, 9th row of C column should be '1' instead of '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
import numpy as np
df['LastTB'] = (df.A * df.TB.replace({'':np.nan, 'T':True, 'B':True})).fillna(method="ffill")
df['C'] = df.A / df.LastTB.shift()
```

and the output is:

```
    A  UD  ST TB  LastTB         C
0   8   0   0        NaN       NaN
1   2  -1  -1  B     2.0       NaN
2   4   1   1        2.0  2.000000
3   5   1   2        2.0  2.500000
4   6   1   3  T     6.0  3.000000
5   4  -1  -1        6.0  0.666667
6   3  -1  -2  B     3.0  0.500000
7   5   1   1  T     5.0  1.666667
8   5   0   0  T     5.0  1.000000
9   3  -1  -1        5.0  0.600000
10  2  -1  -2        5.0  0.400000
```

If you are determined to write in one line, you can combine both lines:

```
df['C'] = df.A / (df.A * df.TB.replace({'':np.nan, 'T':True, 'B':True})).fillna(method="ffill").shift()
```

Comment: Nice answer, you could use `1` instead of `True` in your `replace`. It will work the same as True evaluates to 1, but it is a bit more logical as you need a number for your multiplication. +1

Comment: Thank you, super. Had to look at it for half an hour to understand but I get it now. Still find it weird that you can't use a value from a column in iloc or a function.

Comment: @mozway Yes that's right. But I am more comfortable with boolean as I am using it as a mask. It's kinda personal preference.