# Python use dataframe column value in iloc (or shift)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Although my previous question was answered here [Python dataframe new column with value based on value in other row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799905/python-dataframe-use-column-value-in-iloc-or-any-other-function?noredirect=1#comment121590812_68799905) I still want to know how to use a column value in iloc (or shift or rolling, etc.)

I have a dataframe with two columns A and B, how do I use the value of column B in iloc? Or shift()?

```
d = {'A': [8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3], 'B': [2, -1, 4, 5, 0, -3, 8, 2, 6, -1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Using iloc I get this error.

```
df['C'] = df['A'] * df['A'].iloc[df['B']]

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Using shift() another one.

```
df['C'] = df['A'] * df['A'].shift(df['B'])

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is it possible what I want to do? If yes, how? If no, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy indexing:

```
print (df['A'].to_numpy()[df['B'].to_numpy()])
[4 3 6 4 8 5 5 4 3 3]


df['C'] = df['A'] * df['A'].to_numpy()[df['B'].to_numpy()]
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  8  2  32
1  2 -1   6
2  4  4  24
3  5  5  20
4  6  0  48
5  4 -3  20
6  3  8  15
7  5  2  20
8  5  6  15
9  3 -1   9
```

Comment: Thank you. I've read the to_numpy() docs and I understand it. However, if a dataframe is converted to a NumPy array, the .shift() and other functions are not available anymore, so this solution will not work for that. Is there a way to achieve this? And if it's a silly question, I also would like to know:)

Answer (score 0):

numpy indexing is the fastest way i agree, but you can use list comprehension + iloc too:

```
d = {'A': [8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3], 'B': [2, -1, 4, 5, 0, -3, 8, 2, 6, -1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['C'] = df['A'] * [df['A'].iloc[i] for i in df['B']]

   A  B   C
0  8  2  32
1  2 -1   6
2  4  4  24
3  5  5  20
4  6  0  48
5  4 -3  20
6  3  8  15
7  5  2  20
8  5  6  15
9  3 -1   9
```

Comment: Thank you. Never thought of this way. I've tried this with df['C'] = df['A'] * [df['A'].shift(i) for i in df['B']] but that raises an error 'ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional' which I find weird because i is 1-dimensional as far as I understand.

Comment: Hi, I think the problem isn't coming from shift() but comes from the multiplication between df['A'] and [df['A'].shift(i) for i in df['B']]. Indeed, the list comprehension results in a list of pd.Series (each Serie beeing the results of the shift on A depending on B value) and is then not 1-D but will results in a array of (10;10) = 10 series of 10 values each. you can see it easily by doing t = np.array([df['A'].shift(i) for i in df['B']]) and t.shape. In contrast, iloc[i] will only extract the value of A depending on B index and will then results in a 1-D array [4, 3, 6, 4, 8, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3]

Comment: Yes, I see. And I think I understand. Still find it's strange though:)